# Probability that a geometric random variable is even

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

**Original Question:** 
Toss an unfair coin until we get HEAD. Suppose the total number of tosses is a random variable $X$, and $Pr(HEAD) = p$. What is the probability that $X$ is even? Denote this event as $A$.

**Argument 1:** We know that random variable $X$ can be either even or odd, so $Pr(A)=\frac{1}{2}$.

**Argument 2:**

$Pr(A)=Pr(X\ is\ even)=\sum_{k\ is\ even} (1-p)^{k-1}p=p((1-p)+(1-p)^3 + (1-p)^5 + \dots)=\frac{p(1-p)}{1-(1-p)^2}=\frac{1-p}{2-p} $

Which one is correct? Thanks!

Comment: Just because there are only two possibilities does not mean they are equally likely. There is no symmetry here, the first argument is not correct.

Comment: To understand why $P(A)$ depends on $p$, consider the case $p=1$. If $p=1$, then $X=1$ and $P(A)=0$. It is indeed given by the answer 2.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Nice observation, thanks! One comment, suppose the second argument is true, then we notice that as $p$ increases, $Pr(A)$ would decrease. Any intuitive explanation for this?

Comment: @mookid Aha! I got it, thank you :)

Comment: As head gets more likely, the probability the game is over in the first round (odd number) increases. This is the dominant term, so to probability "odd" wins increases.

Comment: By the way, let $a$ be the probability of **odd**. $X$ is odd if (i) we get head on first or (ii) get tail, tail, and then our probability is $a$. It follows that $a=p +(1-p)^2 a$. Solve for $a$. We get $a=\frac{p}{2p-p^2}=\frac{1}{2-p}$. Probability of even is now easy to compute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argument 3: $X$ is even exactly when the first toss is Tails, which happens with probability $1-p$, and when the remaining number of tosses is odd, which happens with conditional probability $1-P(A)$. Thus, $P(A)=(1-p)(1-P(A))$.

Comment: This is a smart one :) Thanks!

Comment: (+1) Conditional solutions are quite often the most elegant.